# How can I extend an OHLCItem class and use it in OHLCSeries

Tags: java, inheritance, jfreechart

I would like to extend behaviour of an [OHLCItem](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/ohlc/OHLCItem.html) class from the JFreeChart library and I would like to use those custom objects to build an [OHLCSeries](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/ohlc/OHLCSeries.html) with them. This works ok. However, when I am trying to retrieve those objects from the OHLCSeries using the `getDataItem(int index)` method, I only receive [ComparableObjectItem](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/ComparableObjectItem.html) objects which can be only casted to OHLCItem, but can not be casted to my custom class. Here's how I define my custom class:

```
public class CustomOHLCItem extends OHLCItem {
private boolean isJoinedCandle;
private OHLCItem clickedItem;
private OHLCItem neighbourItem;
public CustomOHLCItem(RegularTimePeriod period, double open, double high, double low, double close, boolean isJoinedCandle) {
    super(period, open, high, low, close);
    this.isJoinedCandle = isJoinedCandle;
}

public boolean isJoinedCandle() {
    return isJoinedCandle;
}

public OHLCItem getClickedItem() {
    return clickedItem;
}

public void setClickedItem(OHLCItem clickedItem) {
    this.clickedItem = clickedItem;
}

public OHLCItem getNeighbourItem() {
    return neighbourItem;
}

public void setNeighbourItem(OHLCItem neighbourItem) {
    this.neighbourItem = neighbourItem;
}
```

}

So, is there any way I can retrieve objects of my custom class from the OHLCSeries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look through the source code for the `OHLCSeries` class, you'll see the issue pretty quickly (in the `add(OHCLItem)` method).  You will need to create your own `CustomOHLCSeries` class.